# Print or return the request arguments/form data

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, flask, werkzeug

I am using wsgi-request-logger https://github.com/pklaus/wsgi-request-logger in a flask application and need it to also log the request parameters (ie. the arguments that would be sent with the request).

Using request.form or request.args doesn't work and returns -

RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

---

`val['params'] = url_decode(environ.get('QUERY_STRING', ''))
print val['params']`

This does not work and returns MultiDict([]) (tried it in middleware and the views.py file, it returns the same thing for both cases).

---

```
if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST':
   print parse_form_data(environ)[1]
```

This returns MultiDict[] too.

I don't get what I am missing here. Help would be great.

---

Code which calls the middleware. I edited the middleware a bit and changed the files name to request_logger_wsgi as Im testing it with a local clone right now.

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import app

from request_logger_wsgi import WSGILogger, ApacheFormatters
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler


def application(environ, start_response):
        response_body = 'The request method was %s' % environ['REQUEST_METHOD']
        response_body = response_body.encode('utf-8')
        response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/plain'),
                            ('Content-Length', str(len(response_body)))]
        start_response('200 OK', response_headers)
        print response_body, "231321"
        return [response_body]

handlers = [ TimedRotatingFileHandler('access.log', 'd', 7) , ]
app.wsgi_app = WSGILogger(app.wsgi_app, handlers, ApacheFormatters.format_log)

app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should post more code of your application, otherwise it's very difficult to help.

You can't use Flask's `request` object in the WSGI layer. The `wsgi-request-logger` runs before Flask, that's why there is no request context yet.

You other code was probably run in a module and you used `os.environ`, which is different from the WSGI environment.

What you actually have to do is to create a custom formatter and tell

```
def query_formatter(status_code, environ, content_length):
    return "{0} {1} {2}".format(dt.now().isoformat(), status_code,
                                environ.get('QUERY_STRING', ''))
```

And then set the formatter:

```
app = WSGILogger(application, handlers, query_formatter)
```

It would however be better to reuse one of the Apache formatters instead:

```
import requestlogger

def apache_query_formatter(status_code, environ, content_length):
    return requestlogger.ApacheFormatters.format_NCSA_log(
        status_code, environ, content_length) + environ.get('QUERY_STRING', '')
```

This formatter will use the NCSA format and append the query string. There are probably better formats for the log message, but this should get you started.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I edited my OP and added more code. If any more is needed I will add that too.

Comment: The query string will not give me arguments in case of POST requests though?

Comment: It won't give you form data, no. But query strings can also be provided to a POST requests **in addition** to form data. Do you really want to log POST requests? They may contain a lot of data and you have to worry about the encoding of the data. If a form uses `multipart/form-data` for example the POST request can contain newlines.